# How to Deattach/Not Track Entity after Add/Update/Remove in EF Core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

In Our Project we are using EF Core 3.1 , as it is generated Entity as POCO so we are using these POCO as models to be used in Controller,BAL and DAL (DAL is of Unit of Work and Respository). 
During DB Context registration in Startup file we have marked DB context no trackable.

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationHandler.AppSettings.DBConnection).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
```

> So now we are looking a way to keep these models independent means if
>   we are using these models to add/update data in DAL(Repository) then
>   this should to be not tracked even after save,update and delete.

```
 Student getData = await Repository.GetEntityAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);

 getData.Name = "Update With Repository Method";
 Repository.Update(getData);
 getData.Name = "Modify entity after Repository Update Method.";
 await unitOfWork.CommitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In above method name value saved in DB is "Modify entity after Repository Update Method" but we want it only "Update With Repository Method". So if we call update method then this model(Student) should not be trackable.

Update Method Implementation in Repository

```
 public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
       DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Commit Method Implementation in Unit of Work :

```
public async Task<bool> CommitAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Unit of Work is the DbContext itself. The repository is the DbSet itself. `SaveChangesAsync` actually persists the changes. Before calling this nothing is sent to the database. Your code uses the "Generic Repository" **anti**pattern in an unusal way, eg that `Update` doesn't update anything, it attaches a detached entity.

Comment: Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: The solution is to ditch the generic repository. You *have* to keep tracking entities until `SaveChanges` is called. You don't need (actually shouldn't) keep a DbContext around for any longer than necessary. Simply using `AddDbContext` ensures you have a request-scoped "domain transaction" - if you call `SaveChanges` at the end, everything is saved. If not, everything is discarded. You don't need anything extra.

Comment: In your code, that `Update` method isn't even needed - setting the `Name` property arleady marks the object for update (assuming `GetEntityAsync` doesn't do something weird like detaching the object, or using `AsNoTracking`).

Comment: "The Unit of Work is the DBContext  itself " i will come back on this. and yes we are using no tracking and that i have mentioned that in first code line.

Comment: `we are using No tracking` There's your bug then. Don't do that. You're loading an entity to modify it so you *have* to track it

Comment: we are not only treating these classes as entities , we are also considering these as models to use in different layer, so there is no point of keeping them tracked at first place. That's why disconnected scenario comes in to picture. And there nothing like that we can't use no tracking.

Comment: But EF is already disconnected - once you execute a query, the connection closes, whether tracking is enabled or not. You don't need to make any change to it to make it disconnected. `there is no point of keeping them tracked at first place.` yes there is. If you don't, you can't update the entities. If you want untracked entities occasionally, write a different method.  `we are also considering these as models` that doesn't matter, EF works with POCOs.

Comment: I'd suggest following one of the ASP.NET Core/EF Core tutorials first and *then* decide whether you need to add repositories or modify the data access code. Inspet the database connections and queries eg with SQL Server Profiler or Extended events. Right now you're making a lot of mistaken assumptions about both EF Core and the Repository, UoW pattterns, even what connected/disconnected means. The methods like `Update` and `Commit` do nothing of the kind. The easiest way to clean this up is to start from scratch with a simple scenario